# Delphi How can I detect a click event anywhere on a form including other components

Tags: forms, delphi, onclick, components, frames

I have a `TEdit` in a Delphi VCL form app (contained in a `TFrame` instance, if it matters).  After a user indicates they are finished editing, by clicking elsewhere on the form, the caret and focus remain on this control until I click on another control, which then takes the focus.  However, I want the `TEdit` to loose focus regardless of where the user clicks.  I expect I can use `ActiveControl := nil` to end focus on the selected control, but I am uncertain where to invoke it.

What I want is for the focus to leave the selected control without necessarily having to transfer it to another control.  I could end focus in the form's `OnClick` event, but that will not work if the user selects any of the other controls (also contained in frames) on my form, since the form's `OnClick` event is not triggered.  It seems inelegant and tedious to provide separate `OnClick` events for each additional item on the form.

What is the global solution to achieve this behavior?

Comment: Why would you want this? It's just going to make the user experience worse because it is non standard.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  The program presents a game board and the editors are mostly used by the user during initial setup.  Once the game begins the user gives input including the keyboard and that input that is managed and displayed by the program independent of these editors. 
In the user's view the focus has simply changed to other components consisting of frames containing images and tlabel text displays.

Answer (score 7):

Try using the [`TApplication(Events).OnMessage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnMessage) event to look for [`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttondown) messages.

You can use the VCL's [`FindVCLWindow()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.FindVCLWindow) or [`FindDragTarget()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.FindDragTarget) function (both in the `Vcl.Controls` unit) to see if there is a `TWinControl` located at the click coordinates.  Or simpler, you can use the VCL's [`FindControl()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.FindControl) function (also in the `Vcl.Controls` unit) to get an `TWinControl` directly from the message's target `HWND`.

If no control exists under the mouse, or if the control is not focusable (its `CanFocus()` method returns `False`), then set `ActiveControl=nil`.  Otherwise, do nothing, and let the clicked control take focus on its own when the message is processed.

Comment: @Ashlar `TApplication(Events).OnMessage` sees every message that comes from the main thread's message queue AND is retrieved by a VCL message loop (`TApplication.Run()`, `TForm.ShowModal()`, etc).  Mouse messages are posted to the queue, so `OnMessage` should be seeing them under *normal* conditions. If you are not seeing the messages than perhaps there is a secondary message loop running somewhere in your code that is not passing messages to `OnMessage`. The alternative to using `OnMessage` is to instead use `SetWindowsHookEx()` to install a thread-specific mouse hook in the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks. I found the problem and onMessage is reacting to WM_LButtonDown.  However, FindVCLWindow ( mouse.curpos) returns nil when I click on a tedit.  It appears to be related to mouse.curpos, so separate question is coming

Comment: @Ashlar Why are you using `Mouse.CursorPos` at all, instead of using the coordinates that are provided by `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` itself? The `LParam` contains client coordinates relative to the message's target `HWND`. The mouse may have moved since the time the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message was queued and before it could be retrieved. For that matter, why not just use the message's target `HWND` itself? You can use the VCL's [`FindControl()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.FindControl) function to get a `TWinControl` from an `HWND`.

Comment: Your comment here and other similar comments on [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61129468/delphi-mouse-curpos-appears-to-be-returning-incorrect-coordinates)  have me correcting my code as you suggest.  I am just learning to use messages correctly so your info on `LParam` is new info to me and very helpful. I have more research to conduct!