# Delphi Mouse.curpos appears to be returning incorrect coordinates

Tags: delphi, coordinates, mouse

I have a VCL form application with a `tedit` that will use `FindVCLWindow (Mouse.CursorPos)` to act upon a  the control if it is beneath the mouse.  When I left click on the tedit, my program returns `nil` for the result and the reason appears to be the mouse.curpos sent in the function.  In my test I used a form size of 500+ x 500+ and located it at screen coordinates 100,100. The `Tedit` is located at 100,100 and is sized and displayed at 100,50.  When  I point at the edit, the `mouse.curpos` is returned as 1093,67 and the `ScreentoClient(Mouse.CursorPos)` is 901,-141. Either coordinate set misses the `tedit` rectangle in both directions. Clearly these locations are outside of the `tedit` rectangle although I clicked inside its rectangle. I had assumed that the mouse coordinates use screen coordinates, but I cannot make sense of what it is doing.  How do I resolve this?

EXAMPLE:
MessageTest.dfm

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Message Test'
  ClientHeight = 461
  ClientWidth = 484
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 102
    Top = 51
    Width = 60
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Label1'
    Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clWindowText
    Font.Height = -21
    Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
    Font.Style = []
    ParentFont = False
  end
  object Edit1: TEdit
    Left = 100
    Top = 100
    Width = 100
    Height = 50
    AutoSize = False
    Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clWindowText
    Font.Height = -21
    Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
    Font.Style = []
    ParentFont = False
    TabOrder = 0
    Text = 'Edit1'
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 102
    Top = 184
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Test'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
end
```

messageTest_u.pas

```
unit MessageTest_u;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

const
  WM_LOSEFOCUS = WM_USER + 2000;  //testing value
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure AppMessage(var Msg: TMsg; var Handled: Boolean);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm1.AppMessage(var Msg: TMsg; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  msgStr: String;
  pos : tpoint;
  FormTop, FormLeft, EditTop, EditLeft, EditWidth, EditHeight : integer;
  tmpControl : tWinControl;
begin
//  if Msg.hwnd = Application.Handle then  begin
    if Msg.message = WM_LOSEFOCUS then begin
      showMessage ('WM_LOSEFOCUS Received');
      Handled := True;
    end;

    if Msg.message = WM_LBUTTONDOWN then begin
      formTop := form1.Top;
      formLeft := form1.Left;
      editTop := Edit1.Top;
      editLeft := edit1.Left;
      editWidth := Edit1.Width;
      editHeight := Edit1.Height;

      pos := ScreentoClient(Mouse.CursorPos);
      tmpControl := FindVCLWindow (Mouse.CursorPos);
      if (tmpControl = nil) then begin
        if (tmpControl.canfocus = false) then begin // definitely outside of a tedit
          showMessage ('WM_LBUTTONDOWN Received');
          ActiveControl := nil;
          Handled := True;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  { For all other messages, Handled remains False }
  { so that other message handlers can respond. }
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(Application.Handle, WM_LOSEFOCUS, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnMessage := AppMessage;
  Form1.top := 100;
  form1.left := 100;
  edit1.top := 100;
  edit1.left := 100;
end;

end.
```

Comment: `Mouse.CursorPos` is just a thin wrapper for the Win32 [`GetCursorPos()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorpos) which returns screen coordinates. Given the numbers you have provided, there is no way the mouse coordinates can be 1093x67 when clicking on the `TEdit`. The 1093 *might* make sense if your `TForm` is on a 2nd monitor, but the 67 just makes no sense. You are going to have to provide a [mcve] showing exactly what you are doing. And why are you using `Mouse.CursorPos` at all instead of the coordinates provided by the click you are handling?

Comment: How is your DPI setting for that screen?

Comment: `cursr := GetCursorPos();` should be `GetCursorPos(cursr);`, former shouldn't compile. `FindVCLWindow` accepts screen coordinates, get rid of `ScreenToClient`. `FindVCLWindow` won't return nil when you click on a form, it will return the form.

Comment: @UweRaabe 96DPI What is confusing me is that clicking on the tedit sets the focus for it and allows editing, but the correct location is not returned to my code.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz  Yep,  That was some old code that I removed from the question.  `ScreentoClient` was an attempt to see which coordinates were supposed to be returned and was also removed.  I don't recall what result is returned by `FindVCLWindow` when I click the form and am currently reinstalling Delphi in case there is a problem there.  Will check when its done.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem with the code you have provided. As there are no code to show the coordinates, I presume that you have a break point to be able to read the coords. But perhaps you move your mouse before the line `pos := ScreentoClient(Mouse.CursorPos);`. For a better test, remove break points and  add following code just before you set `pos`: `caption := format('mouse.cursorpos = %d, %d', [Mouse.CursorPos.X, Mouse.CursorPos.Y]);` to show actual coords at mouse click in the forms caption.

Comment: @Ashlar a better solution is to use `FindControl()` instead of `FindVCLWindow()`, eg: `tmpControl := FindControl(Msg.hwnd); if (tmpControl = nil) or (tmpControl is TForm) or (not tmpControl.CanFocus) then ...`

Comment: @TomBrunberg OK I am embarrassed.  Your suggestion was excellent and made me realize that the problem is that I was running the program in debug and the location of `mouse.cursorpos` was set after I returned to the delphi code screen, hence the wrong location.  The caption shows the correct mouse location. THANKS for the help